Frontend & Backend .htaccess redirects with a single Base-URI
I tried so many things but Failed for now:
I have a webspace where I can work with .htaccess files. I have an angular frontend and a php backend written with the symfony framework.
Folders:
/[frontend]
/api/[backend]
/api/public/
Files:
/.htaccess(1)
/index.html (Angular entry point)
/api/.htaccess(2)
/api/public.htaccess(3)
/api/public.index.php(Symfony entry point)
I struggle with where I should have what .htaccess files to get it all working.
A list of URLs with examples where they should point:
myweb.com/ -> display index.html (works)
myweb.com/about -> redirect to index.html and angular will handle sub path (works)
myweb.com/api -> redirect to /api/public/index.php (Does not work error 403)
myweb.com/api/brand/new -> redirect to /api/public/index.php and symfony will handle sub paths after /api/ (semi works, does not find anything under that api but is handled by index.php)
myweb.com/api/public/brand/new -> this works but I don't want the public in the url
I don't want the /public/ to appear in the url.
Is this constellation even possible?
I got Angular working with this in .htaccess (1)
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/api/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^ /index.html [L]

Symfony provides this ´.htaccess (3)´ file. This Does work perfectly if symfony has its own URL and is located in Root and I have a .htaccess(2) file in root.
.htaccess (3)
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$0 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
    RewriteRule .* - [E=BASE:%1]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .+
    RewriteRule ^ - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%0]

    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} =""
    RewriteRule ^index\.php(?:/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$1 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ %{ENV:BASE}/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
        RedirectMatch 307 ^/$ /index.php/
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>

.htaccess (2)
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /api/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /api/public/index.php [L]

